MariaDB indexing foreign keys
When using InnoDB engine, do foreign keys that reference primary keys in other tables require their own index.
Similarly, in composite keys, obviously a primary key (a,b,c,d) wouldnt work on (b,c) so if b and c are foriegn keys that reference primary keys in other tables shouldn't they arleady have their indexes created automatically

What have you tried?  Show actual examples that you have a question about.  Does https://mariadb.com/kb/en/foreign-keys/ answer your question?

"...obviously a primary key (a,b,c,d) wouldnt work on (b,c)..." -- That's not true. They can be used, sometimes even in an optimal way. It all depends on the query.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.


do foreign keys that reference primary keys in other tables require their own index.

They require an index. If no suitable index exists already, then a new index will be created when you declare the foreign key constraint. But if an index already exists with the foreign key column(s) as the leftmost in the index, that index will be used and no new index will be created.
Example:
create table MyTable (
  id int primary key,
  x int,
  y int,
  z int,
  index (x, y, z)
);

If I add a foreign key on x to another table, it can use the existing index, since x is the leftmost column in the index.
If I add a foreign key on y to another table, it must create a new index, because it can't use the existing index in which y is not the leftmost column.
alter table MyTable
  add foreign key (x) references OtherTable (id),
  add foreign key (y) references OtherTable (id);

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/qmW2GiC-
The resulting table:
CREATE TABLE `MyTable` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `x` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `y` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `z` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `x` (`x`,`y`,`z`),
  KEY `y` (`y`),
  CONSTRAINT `MyTable_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`x`) REFERENCES `OtherTable` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `MyTable_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`y`) REFERENCES `OtherTable` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4

See that a new index was created for y.

MySQL/MariaDB/SQL Server/Sybase create indexes for FKs by default. Depending on the day I find that useful or wasteful. Granted, it offers an instant performance gain for some queries at the expense of a [tiny] extra index/cost. Still can't make up my mind about this.

It also makes it efficient for referential integrity checks, for example if you try to update or delete a row in the parent table, it needs to check the foreign key column to make sure there are no references that would block such an action. If it had to do a table-scan to make this check, it would cause performance problems.

Yes, that's true.
